# File Transfer Protocol and an AS400

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm currently receiving the following error:

*The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.*

I've physically checked the server and the file does indeed exist, if I open a Command Prompt and type the following code it works:

```
ftp
open 192.168.1.2
cd /Images
get S12345.jpeg
```

That works correctly, however as soon as I attempt to connect via this code:

```
private bool DownloadPod(string server)
{
     string[] allocate = server.Split('\\');
     string ftp = @"ftp://192.168.1.2/Images/" + allocate.Last();
     Uri uri = new Uri(ftp);

     // The code path for uri: ftp://192.168.1.2/Images/S12345.jpeg
     var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as FtpWebRequest;
     if(request != null)
     {
           request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
           // Left credentials off for security.
           request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"", @"");
           // The line that triggers the error (response)
           using(FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse)
                using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                     using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                     {
                           reader.ReadToEnd();
                           return true;
                     }
      }
     return false;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working?

- Credentials work in Command Prompt
- File physically on server
- Can download from Command Prompt

According the MSDN:

> To obtain an instance of FtpWebRequest, use the Create method. You can
>   also use the WebClient class to upload and download information from
>   an FTP server. Using either of these approaches, when you specify a
>   network resource that uses the FTP scheme (for example,
>   "ftp://contoso.com") the FtpWebRequest class provides the ability to
>   programmatically interact with FTP servers.
>
> The URI may be relative or absolute. If the URI is of the form
>   "ftp://contoso.com/%2fpath" (%2f is an escaped '/'), then the URI is
>   absolute, and the current directory is /path. If, however, the URI is
>   of the form "ftp://contoso.com/path", first the .NET Framework logs
>   into the FTP server (using the user name and password set by the
>   Credentials property), then the current directory is set to
>   /path.

Which is how the AS400 is expecting the data to come through.

Comment: did you try that url in your browser? typing in a login, a cd, and a get command in an ftp client is NOT the same as going in via whatever url your code is generating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In certain instances the `/` character isn't valid or accepted.

The AS400 may require a the *change* by utilizing `/%2F`, this will properly switch the directories on the AS400.  For instance:

```
ftp://192.168.1.2/%2FImages/%2FS12345.jpeg
```

By using the `/%2F` it allows it to move between directories.

Additional details can be found [here](https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/ftpwebrequest-access-ibm-as400-ftp-38178.aspx).